# wordpress update will overwrite files changes?

Tags: updates, core

I edit function.php and page.php files for my custom use, everything is fine, but i have query that if wordpress will update then it will overwrite all the files and changes made ??

Comment: If you are only referring to WordPress updates then no it will not change your theme or plugins. Theme and plugins are updated separately and manually. When updating WordPress, it overwrite all core files and folder except `wp-content`.

Comment: it means when i will update theme ... then the files changes will overwrite ?

Comment: Yes. Your changes in theme will only flush on updating your theme.

Comment: thank u very much .... i think there is no option for upvote a comment ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, theme update will overwrite its folder completely. If you are using third party theme with possibility of updates the normal practice is to put your customizations into a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for it.